# Why is gdb printing registers values in that way

Tags: linux, assembly, gdb

So I have a task, where I have to compare like 128 bit numbers using 32 bit registers. So I thought about checking every bit (from the left), and comparing it with the othe number. I have this situation:

I've got a `.txt` file, where I have two `16`-byte numbers written (no spaces or newlines), like this:

`00000000000000010000000000000003`

I read them using syscalls (`x86` not 64 bit) and store in 2 buffers. When I want to take a byte from them, I do:

```
movl $15, %eax
addl $NUMBER1, %eax
movzbl (%eax), %eax
```

So now I have the last byte of that number in `%eax` (indices of course begin from zero). Then I go for:
`btl $0, %eax`.

So in this case it shoudl be easy. I got a byte `1` stored in eax. I check its first bit (from the right side, of course), so 32 bit `1` = `000000000000000000000000000000001`, so I should get 1 in `carry flag`. I check it with `jc carry_1` - of course, it works. But then, I tried to check for something else. Cause obviously I shouldn't compare two numbers starting from the least significant digits, I should start from the left. So I go for `btl $31, %eax`, and yes, of course in this case I get `0` in carry flag. So I just wanted to check how my `%eax` looks, just to make sure I didn't get anything by an accident.

So in gdb I launched my executable. I got to the line with `movzbl`, I've gone through that line. Now it's time to check:

`print /t $eax`. I though I will get: `000000000000000000000000000000001`, but no. The thing I saw:

```
33      movzbl (%eax), %eax
(gdb) s
34      btl $31, %eax
(gdb) print /t $eax
$1 = 110001
```

So why is it `110001`? When I checked for the `3` it was `110011`, so the end of this is correct, but whats with those `11` at the beggining? I mean its for sure not a sign bit from `twos complement` (cuz there would be only one + it would be zero as my numbers are positive). So do you know what is it?

I am compiling it on a Manjaro 64 bit with `as --32` and `ld -melf_i1386`

Comment: That "16-byte number" looks more like 32 bytes long ASCII string, probably representing hexadecimal encoding (like `"12AB"` meant as value `0x12AB` after proper conversion). When you have to **compare** them, you can compare them as strings, no need to convert them into numbers, the ASCII characters keep all important features of numeric values, like `'0' < '1' < '9' < 'A' < 'F'`, so if both numbers are with leading zeroes, 32 chars long, then just comparing char by char will tell which is less/greater/equal in unsigned way. And you don't need to compare bit by bit, dword by dword `cmp` is OK.

Comment: The `cmp` part explained... to simplify I will compare 8 chars long string only `"01234567" vs "0123456A"` -> when you load first 4 bytes of both strings, you will get value `0x33323130`, `cmp` will end with ZF=1 ("equal"). The last 4 bytes will be `0x37363534` vs `0x41363534`, so `cmp` will tell second num is "above" (correct, by accident). And I nicely caught myself lying, as the string is "big endian" and x86 "little endian", `"0100" vs "0010"` will end as `0x30303130 vs 0x30313030` => second "above" => wrong answer. So in ASCII you have to `cmp` char by char. Dword works with num. values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why is it 110001?

You've left out important parts of your code, like the one where you read the numbers from the text file. But it seems very likely that you just read all the characters and stored them somewhere. The ASCII code for the character `'1'` is 49, which in binary (the `/t` switch gives you binary) is `110001`. So if what you've got in memory is the character `'1'`, then this output is entirely expected.

Comment: I've just noticed I am retarded. You are completely right, I've got to this and I came here to say I am stupid, but u were faster :D Thanks